# отношение между классами

Tags: c++, ооп

Можно ли в классе С выполнить расчет `int a / int b` и записать результат в переменную класса С `int c`?

```
class A {
  int a = 5;
};

class B {
  int b = 10;
};

class C {
  friend class A;
  friend class B;
  int c;
};
```

Comment: Можно ли в конструкторе класса С сделать int c = int a / int b?

Comment: Вы изменили код и тем самым исказили текст вопроса и сделали неправильным ответ — это нехорошо. По сути, вы написали ответ вместо вопроса. Пожалуйста, верните изначальный код, а тот код, который вы написали согласно данному вам ответу, оставьте где-нибудь отдельно, например на pastebin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вас интересует тот вопрос, может ли дружественный класс использовать закрытые имена классов, чьим другом он является, то да - например так:

```
#include <iostream>
using  std::cout;
class C;     // вначале обьявите 
class A {
   friend class C;
   int a;
public:
   A() : a(10) { } // в конструкторе инициализировать, а не так как вы сделали
   };

   class B {
     friend class C;
       int b;
   public:
       B() : b(5) {}
   };
   class C {
       int c;  // с это не C, поэтому можно
   public:
       C()  { A t; B k; c = t.a/k.b;}  // нужно создавать обьекты типов
       int get_res() const { return c; }
   };


int main()
{       
    C g;
    std::cout << g.get_res();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не распознает t (там где А t) и k (где B k)

Comment: вы что то написали неправильно, будьте внимательны ( я например оставлял лишную, но привычную мне,  строку для вас) ,  сверьте еще раз

Answer (score 4):

Понимаете, если я скажу, что вы мой друг - вы же меня от **моего** заявления не пустите к себе переночевать?

А вот я вроде как должен, раз заявил, что вы мой друг...

Вот так и у вас - класс `C` заявил, что он - друг `A` и `B`, так что он им доверяет свои внутренности :) А они ему такое доверие не высказали.

Согласитесь, было бы слишком небезопасно - так любой класс, любая функция могли бы получить доступ к любым запрятанным полям - просто объявив о своем желании...

Comment: ой я немного перепутала:) внесла правки) а так?

Comment: Подобные правки в САМ ВОПРОС лучше не вносить. Лучше загрузить на хостинг кода вроде pastebin - ибо при правках, вроде Вашей, люди, читающие этот вопрос много позже, не поймут его сути. Предложил правку, возвращающую вопрос к состоянию до правки (только код). Также немного исправил форматирование, улучшив читабельность.

Comment: А по факту, автор ответа всё правильно объяснил - Ваш новый вариант должен работать нормально.

Comment: class A не может иметь класса C  как друга,  так как он не в области видимости...и нельзя в классе так инициализировать (int a = 5; )

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, это решается обьявлением `class C;` перед использованием класса С - то-же самое, что и с функциями и структурами.

Comment: @Ancient, да, но у автора вопроса нет этого обьявления

Comment: Про инициализацию - да, Вы правы, но это уже другой вопрос. @MarynaSaid, инициализировать переменные-члены класса надо в конструкторе. Желательно используя список инициализаций.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ибо вопрос состоял по-другому - классы А и В не использовали С - всё было наоборот. Просто автор вопроса отредактировал код в вопросе вместо загрузки нового варианта на pastebin. Читайте выше - я предложил правку, восстанавливающую исходный вариант.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере нет никакого `a` и нет никакого `b`.

В вашем примере есть только нестатические поля классов `A::a` и `B::b`. Нестатические поля классов не существуют физически сами по себе. Нестатические поля классов существуют только внутри *объектов* (экземпляров) этих классов, только вместе с этими объектами. Поэтому, пока вы не создадите объекты этих классов, никаких `a` и `b` не будет.

Если у вас на руках есть экземпляр `aa` класса `A` и экземпляр `bb` класса `B`, то вы, при наличии соответствующих прав доступа, сможете запросто вычислить значение `aa.a / bb.b`. Но пока у вас нет таких экземпляров, то и говорить не о чем, ибо никаких `a` и `b` не существует.

У вас в коде я не вижу ни малейшего намека то, что класс `C` работает с какими-то экземплярами классов `A` и `B`. А без экземпляров ни о каких `a` и `b` и говорить не приходится.